# Can we always permute Cohen reals?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Consider the Cohen forcing, and suppose that $\dot x,\dot y$ are names for reals, which are not in the ground model (i.e. $1$ forces that neither is in the ground model).

Can we always find an automorphism mapping $\dot x$ to $\dot y$?

The answer is negative, as Andreas Blass points out. But let me refine the question a lot more.

Suppose $p$ is a condition which forces that $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are both generic with respect to the restriction of the forcing to $A$ (i.e. take only conditions whose domain is a subset of $A$ and complete that to the subalgebra of the Cohen forcing). Is there an automorphism $\pi$ such that $p\Vdash\pi\dot x=^*\dot y$?

Of course, this depends on how you consider the Cohen forcing, so let's take the "richest" way, and consider it as the completion of functions from finite sets of integers to $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because reals not in the ground model can be different in definable (with parameters from the ground model) ways.  For example, $\dot x$ might be (forced by all conditions to be) a Cohen-generic subset of $\omega$, while $\dot y$ is the intersection of $\dot x$ with the set of even numbers.  Then $\dot y$ is disjoint from an infinite ground-model set of natural numbers but $\dot x$ is not.

EDIT to answer the edited version of the question: The answer is still negative, if $A$ is an infinite, coinfinite, ground-model subset of $\omega$. Let $\dot c$ be (the canonical name of) the Cohen subset of $\omega$ directly added by the forcing.  Let $\dot x$ be the intersection of $\dot c$ with $A$.  Let $\dot y$ be a copy on $A$ of all of $\dot c$, i.e., the $n$-th element of $A$ is in $\dot y$ iff $n\in\dot c$.  Then both $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are generic with respect to the Cohen forcing over $A$. They are not related by an automorphism of the forcing, because $\dot y$ generates (over the original ground model) the whole forcing extension (the same as $\dot c$) while $\dot x$ generates only an intermediate model.

Comment: Addendum: Not even if both $\dot x$ and $\dot y$ are Cohen-generic over the ground model will they necessarily be connected by an automorphism of the forcing.  For example, $\dot x$ might generate your whole Cohen extension, while $\dot y$ generates some intermediate submodel.

Comment: Right, I was just thinking about adding a clause regarding this. But posting and editing from your phone is really annoying. I apologize for the trouble. although it seems like the idea can be generalized further to the interesting case.

Comment: Sorry for the very late edit, but it arrived.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've just edited my answer to address the edited version of the question. The answer is still negative, for essentially the same reason.

Comment: I have a related question which I don't think merits a whole new thread. Let $\dot c$ be the canonical name for a real. Can we find a permutation $\pi$ of the forcing such that $\Bbb R^{L[c]}$ and $\Bbb R^{L[\pi c]}$ are different?

Comment: @Asaf What exactly do you mean by "canonical"? I know of canonical names for ground model reals, and for the generic real directly added by the forcing, and for some other specific reals (or, rather, descriptions of reals), but I don't see a clear notion of canonical names for just any real in the extension.

Comment: By canonical name I meant $\{(p,\check n)\mid p(n)=1\}$, of course.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So your $\dot c$ is not just some real but the generic real directly added by the forcing. You also seem to be taking the forcing to be just the set of finite partial functions $\omega\to2$, not the completion mentioned in the last sentence of the question. Now if the automorphism $\pi$ is in $L$, then $L[c]=L[\pi c]$, but if not 9so $\pi$ is in the ground model but not in $L$) then I would think one could code non-constructible information into $\pi$ and thus make the models different.

Comment: Andreas thanks for the answer, although earlier today I realized that my situation is in fact much simpler than this case and solved it. Thanks for the answer, though!